# Why WebViews have their own lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I have several WebViews in my fragment that each shows a youtube player in an iframe, when playing those videos i noticed that pausing the fragment and even the activity didnt effect the WebView and the video kept on playing in the background.

I fixed it by keeping those WebViews in a list, applying the fragment lifecycle on them :

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    for (WebView wv : webviews)
        wv.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    for (WebView wv : webviews)
        wv.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    for (WebView wv : webviews)
        wv.destroy();
    webviews.clear();
}
```

Now its working quite well, though im left curious about why this is heppenning? why would WebViews run on their own and doesnt obbey their container (Activity/Fragment) lifecycle?